# Text is getting blurred after zooming

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, zooming

My scrollView is like this UIViewController --> UIView -->UIScrollView. In the scrollview am tried to zoom the PDF file. after zooming the contents of pdf file are getting blurred.

```
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
for (MagazinePage * page in [self.contentScroll subviews]) {
//maganizepage is a subclass of UIView
//contentScroll is a UIScrollView
    [page removeFromSuperview];
}
int i = 0;
zoomScaleValue = zoomScaleValue+500;

self.contentScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake((self.contentScroll.bounds.size.width+zoomScaleValue) * NO_OF_PAGES_ON_MEMORY,
                                            self.contentScroll.bounds.size.height+zoomScaleValue);
for (MagazinePage * page in collection) {
      page.frame = CGRectMake((i) * self.contentScroll.bounds.size.width+(i*zoomScaleValue), 0.0f,
                                self.contentScroll.bounds.size.width+zoomScaleValue, self.contentScroll.bounds.size.height+zoomScaleValue);

    i++;
    [self.contentScroll addSubview:page];
    }
}

Edit:

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
CFURLRef pdfURL = (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfFilePath]; 
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(pdfURL); 
self.contentScroll.delegate = self; 
self.contentScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.contentScroll.bounds.size.width * noofpages, self.contentScroll.bounds.size.height);
 CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf); collection = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 1; i <= noofpages; i++) { 
    uiviewObject = [[MyUIViewClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i-1) * self.contentScroll.bounds.size.width, 0.0f,self.contentScroll.bounds.size.width, self.contentScroll.bounds.size.height)];
     //uiviewObject subclass of UIView 
    uiviewObject.pdfFileName = pdfName; 
    uiviewObject.pdfFilePath = pdfPath; 
    uiviewObject.pageNumber = _scrollPageNumberToLoad;
     uiviewObject.navigationDelegate = self; 
    [collection addObject:uiviewObject]; 
} 
    [self loadCollectionToContentScroll: collection]; 
}



- (void) loadCollectionToContentScroll: (NSMutableArray *) collectionItems {
for (uiviewObject in [self.contentScroll subviews]) { 
[uiviewObject removeFromSuperview]; 
}
 int i = 0; 
for (uiviewObject in collectionItems) {
uiviewObject.frame = CGRectMake((i) * self.contentScroll.bounds.size.width, 0.0f, self.contentScroll.bounds.size.width, self.contentScroll.bounds.size.height);
i++; 
[self.contentScroll addSubview:uiviewObject];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is the correct behaviour, you will loose quality when the scrollview is zoomed with a PDF inside it. You got to to re-render the PDF, see this https://github.com/vfr/Reader to get an intro.

Comment: could you please explain in detail how to re-render the pdf.. i check that code but not able to find.

Comment: See this, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/layerClass

Answer (score 1):

You got to add this method in the UIView class of yours to support tiling which prevents your PDF content from being blurred.

```
+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [YourCustomContentTile class];
}
```

YourCustomContentTile.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface YourCustomContentTile :  CATiledLayer {

}

@end
```

YourCustomContentTile.m

```
@implementation YourCustomContentTile

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        self.levelsOfDetail = 5;

        self.levelsOfDetailBias = (5 - 1);

        CGFloat screenScale;

        UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];

        if ([mainScreen respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
            screenScale = [mainScreen scale];
        else
            screenScale = 1.0f;

        CGRect screenBounds = [mainScreen bounds]; 

        CGFloat w_pixels = (screenBounds.size.width * screenScale);
        CGFloat h_pixels = (screenBounds.size.height * screenScale);

        CGFloat max = (w_pixels < h_pixels) ? h_pixels : w_pixels;

        CGFloat sizeOfTiles = (max < 512.0f) ? 512.0f : 1024.0f;

        self.tileSize = CGSizeMake(sizeOfTiles, sizeOfTiles);
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Actually i don't have any separate class for ScrollView, drag the UIScrollView on UIViewController-->UIView. and bind this scrollView. In UIViewController am using that scrollView. Added the above code, but getting the same effect as above

Comment: Ok no problem add this to your existing class and see.

Comment: + (Class)layerClass is not calling, after double click i suppose this should be called, but this method not getting called. I have to call this method or it will call automatically..

Comment: Can you show me how you are drawing the PDF page onto your view??

Comment: Dude kindly update your question, code is not readable in comments.

Comment: Please check my Edited Comments